# how to show html in grails?

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have a domain class that has a string variable containing HTML code. I want to display this code on myxml.gsp.

For this I've written the following code:

**Learn.groovy**

```
public class Learn {

    String content = ("<html><head><title>Learning Grails</title>
       <body>Grails is fun</body></html>");

}
```

**myxml.gsp**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Xml Output</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>${learn.content}<p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

However it is unable to fetch value for "content", getting the error: `"Cannot get property 'content' on null object"`. What I am doing wrong? Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean "unable to fetch value"? What is the resulting HTML between <p> and </p>?

Comment: Could you provide us code of your controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to display HTML markup to user, use `${learn.content.encodeAsHTML()}`.

For `Cannot get property 'content' on null object` error, looks you're passing a null `learn` object or not passing it at all. Check that you have something like: `[...(something), learn: learnInstance]` returned from your action.

If it's OK to have null `learn` in GSP (which I don't recommend) - use `${learn?.content?.encodeAsHTML()}`.

Answer (score 13):

I use this:

${raw(htmlString)}